# Wordpress WooCommerce text attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce plugin in Wordpress. In that plugin I need to add text input for each product where in clients can fill in the additional product details.

The problem I am facing is that whenever I Add Text Attribute, it changes to a select box. Please suggest some solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean that your clients should have this text input field available on frontend?

If it's just backend, you can add this to your functions.php:

```
if (is_admin()){     
// Add the Meta Box  
function add_textfield() {  
    add_meta_box(  
        'textfield', // $id  
        'Custom textfield', // $title   
        'show_textfield_backend', // $callback  
        'product', // $page  
        'normal', // $context  
        'high'  // $priority
    ); 
}  
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_textfield');

// The Callback  
function show_textfield_backend() {  
    global $post;  
    global $wpdb;

    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'textfield', true);

    // Use nonce for verification  
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="textfield_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';  

    _e('Custom textfield: ');
    echo '<input type="text" placeholder="text" id="textfield" class="textfield" name="textfield" ', $meta ? " value='$meta'" : "",' />';       
}

// Save the Data  
function save_textfield($post_id) {  
    global $wpdb;

    // verify nonce  
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['textfield_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
        return $post_id;
    // check autosave  
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
        return $post_id;
    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
            return $post_id;  
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
        return $post_id;  
    }

    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

        $textfield = $_POST['textfield'];
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'textfield', $textfield);

    }  
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_textfield');
}
```

Comment: So, it wasn't what you needed? You need something front-end?